# What is the best way to handle audits in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, audit

We track any action in the system so we use `@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)` on entities that listen for any action.

code snippet:

```
public class AuditListener {

    @Autowired
    private AuditRepository auditRepo; 

    @PrePersist
    public void preSave(Object object) {
        // save audit to database
    }
}
```

so what is the best to use `@PrePersist` or `@PostPersist`?

Comment: Well, do you want to audit before or after a `persist` operation?

Comment: I want to create an audit if an entity has already been added or updated successfully.
So what is the best pre or post?

Comment: I would say `post`. More information is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm#BABIAAGE)

Answer (score 3):

As said by @aksappy, if you wish to audit before or after `insert` you'll have to choose.
But you should know that `@prePersist` `@postPersist` are not the only one to take care of. There are also `@preUpdate` `@postUpdate`. I don't mentionned `@preRemove` `@postRemove` because it seems not possible to audit the remove action (I'm not sure of that one because I haven't tested it myself).

But I can't recommend you enough [`Hibernate Envers`](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) a mature library for auditing/versioning your entities. It's very straightforward to setup and once you are done, it's easy to use on every entities. It'll log every addition, modification and deletion that happen. It's useful when you also want to show history of what happen to an entity, everything is being take care of with the methods provided by `Envers`.

I suggest you take a look at this guide https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa#hibernate and see by yourself. It shows you how to setup `Hibernate Envers` if you want to try it.

Comment: Thanx Pilpo I know all Annotations but search about pre or post.

Comment: Afaik, there is no best option between pre or post. If the `insert` goes wrong, you'll have an exception, the code will stop and the transaction will rollback. So you can't go wrong with either. Maybe it makes more sense to `audit` after the entitie was inserted in DB, so if you think so, you should use `post`. But don't overthink about it, it'll work in any case :)

Comment: Hello, Pilpo.
Does @EntityListener decrease application performance?
I use it on parent class that all other classes extend it.

Comment: It all depends on what work does your EntityListener. If it's a heavy task, yes you'll have impact on your performance., if not, don't worry you're fine.